# broken images | wordpress | Web url images

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a clients live site and I am little stuck into one situation. The client wants images from another website, when putting images into img src tag, the image url is all correct, opening that url in new tab shows the image but not in img src tag.
This is the image tag I am using

```
<img class="lazy" src="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'thumbnail_url', true ); ?>" >
<img class="lazy loading" src="https://i.xcafe.com/videos_screenshots/82000/82577/300x170/8.jpg" data-was-processed="true">
```

the second above code is the output of the first written code
and the console log shows 403 error.
To me everything seems fine, help, am I doing something wrong?

**The display images are broken**

Comment: Let me guess: cross-origin issue? Check your browser's console for more details.

Comment: 403 means forbidden, or permission denied. Based on the nature of that site, they probably don't allow hotlinking. You should contact that site and ask for permission.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to apologize for a slight attitude that I will be giving. But cases like this I take a bit personal. (No, it's not because of the subject matter of the image(s) in question.)

First of all, working on live sites is --- by industry standard --- a no no. You break it, everyone visiting that client's site sees it. This is why you have staging and development (CI/CD) pipelines.

Secondly, does your client own the website they want images from? No? That too is a --- by industry standard --- a no no. Other webmasters and businesses don't like when you steal their bandwidth. This is why they disable ***hot-linking***, which is almost certainly why you're getting a 403 forbidden error. By no means is it alright to use another entity's servers as your CDN. It's unethical and unprofessional.

And don't even think of right clicking, downloading, and using said images that way unless they are CC-BY images. This one is not, and I am sure the others your client wants to use are not either.

#### "miniRant" Over

But I hope it answers your question.